# Text effect not looping properly in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to show the text with `fadein` and `fadeout` continuously. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vicky081/6tTrf/2/) what i experience exactly.

Here is the jquery that i get the message in loop

```
 (function() {

            var message = jQuery("#message_after_login");
            var message_index = 1;

            function shownextmessage() {
                ++message_index;
                message.eq(message_index % message.length)
                        .fadeIn(2000)
                        .delay(2000)
                        .fadeOut(2000, shownextmessage);
            }

            shownextmessage();

        })();
```

Right now it appear first message itself looping like fadein and fadeout, but not the second message. I am not sure where i did mistake.

Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: `id`'s are meant to be unique. use `class` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have 2 elements with same id - [id](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) must be unique, you can use class instead of id here

```
<div class ="message_after_login">Testing for first message</div>
<div class = "message_after_login">This is for testing 2nd message</div>
```

then

```
(function () {

    var message = jQuery(".message_after_login").hide();
    var message_index = -1;

    function shownextmessage() {
        ++message_index;
        message.eq(message_index % message.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, shownextmessage);
    }

    shownextmessage();

})();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WSThg/)

Answer (score 2):

You are repeating ID for two DOM.

`message_after_login` use class instead of ID.

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6tTrf/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Selecting using the ID only selects the first element. If you change it to using class instead of id in your HTML, then use "." instead of "#" in your selector it will work.